# How to prevent from closing window with "Enter" key while the focus in editable control in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, dialog, keyboard-shortcuts

How to prevent from closing window with <kbd>Enter</kbd> key while the focus in editable control?

Usually, I make Cancel with `IsCancel=True` and Ok with `IsDefault=True`.  This is because it will allow users to close a dialog with <kbd>Enter</kbd> as OK and <kbd>Esc</kbd> as Cancel.

However, the problem is pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> key closes the dialog even a keyboard focus is in an editable control such as `TextBox`.
The best behavior is pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> key closes dialog only when the keyboard focus is not in an editable control.  But, pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> key twice should close the dialog.  Otherwise, users need to change keyboard focus to another non-editable control to close with <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

So, as a workaround, I implemented this way:

- Intercepting `KeyDown` event and check
  if it's <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.
- If so, check if the keyboard focus is
  at Ok button.
- If so, closes the dialog with Ok
  button.  Otherwise, change the
  keyboard focus to Ok button.  So, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> key twice will close the dialog.

This has a problem because the first <kbd>Enter</kbd> will change the focus to Ok button, so if the focus is not at the Ok Button, users need to hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> twice.  This is little different from an ideal behavior.  Also, I need to implement this logic to each dialog.

Does someone have a good idea to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If looking for this particular behavior I would just simply set some boolean value to true in the `KeyDown` event handler the first time <kbd>Enter</kbd> gets hit (rather than switching the focus). Then, on the next `KeyDown` event, I'd check if the key hit was <kbd>Enter</kbd> *and* if <kbd>Enter</kbd> has been hit before. To implement this in more than one dialog, I would create a generic dialog where I would override the `OnKeyDown` method rather than subscribing to the event, then subclass that dialog.

(Having said that, as a user I would not like this behavior at all. I would recommend just ignoring the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key altogether when in a text box - that's what users are used to.)

Answer (score 2):

Handle PreviewKeyDown and cancel the event.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the property `IsDefault` of the Ok button to `false`.

Then the click event of the button will be invoked only when the Ok button gets the focus and then by pressing the Enter key or by clicking on it.

Closing the dialog window is automatically activated by setting the `DialogResult` property, to `true` or `false` does not matter.